# What are better alternatives in asp.net MVC to directly accessing the database in the Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Normally I do my data access by instanciating my DbContext globally in my Controller and then I use that manipulate my data.

See below:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private OrtundEntities db = new OrtundEntities();

    public ActionResult Create(CreateUserViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            UserDataModel user = new UserDataModel
            {
                // map view model fields to data model ones
            };

            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // some or other error handling goes here
        }
    }
}
```

It occurs to me that this might not be the ideal way to do it in all applications but aside from implementing a web service for every project I do, I can't think of any alternatives to the above.

So what's a better way to handle the data access on larger projects where the above wouldn't be ideal?

I'm just looking for so-called "best practice" for this or that particular situation. Many opinions will differ on what's the best way so what do you think it is and why?

Comment: I'd consider looking into building repositories and using `dependency injection` and `unit of work` patterns. They're very useful to keep the code concise and clean.

Comment: It just occurred to me that this might not be a question for which any single answer might be correct so now I'm thinking maybe SO isn't the best place for it?

Comment: Repository layer with DI is what you are looking for.

Comment: @StephenBrickner so how does a repo layer with DI work? I've never heard of these things.

Comment: I'll whip up a quick example.

Comment: @Ortund, while waiting on Drew's example a quick overview would be that you have a project for entity which has access to your DB, a repo project which is the only one that has access to the entity project. Other projects needing data now use the repo to get and save data. The DI comes in from the interface describing your repository, which can be injected, mocked, etc.

Comment: sooo db-entity-repo-interface?

Comment: @DrewKennedy - Unit of work is way overboard, since EF is already a unit of work.  Microsoft no longer recommends a UoW on top of EF.  Generic repositories are also consider anti-patterns as they abstract too much and on too granular a scale.  Command and Query objects are a better approach for a larger project.

Answer (score 0):

To help keep your controllers concise and free of direct access to your database, you can implement the `repository` and `dependency injection` patterns. For even more concise code, you can also use the `unit of work` pattern.

Say you had this model:

```
public class Person {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

With the help of generics, you can create an interface to provide a CRUD blueprint:

```
public interface IRepository<T> {
    IEnumerable<T> Get();
    T Get(int? i);
    void Create(T t);
    void Update(T t);
    void Delete(int? i);
}
```

Then create a Repository class that implements the IRepository. This is where all your CRUD will take place:

```
public class PersonRepository : IRepository<Person> {
    private OrtundEntities db = new OrtundEntities();

    public IEnumerable<Person> Get() {
        return db.Persons.ToList();
    }

    //invoke the rest of the interface's methods
    (...)
}
```

Then in your controller you can invoke the `dependency injection` pattern:

```
private IRepository<Person> repo;

public PersonController() : this(new PersonRepository()) { }

public PersonController(IRepository<Person> repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
}
```

And your controller method for, say, `Index()` could look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    return View(repo.Get());
}
```

As you can see this has some useful benefits, including structure to your project, and keeping your controllers easy to maintain.

Comment: Mapping from view model to data model still happens in the controller?

Comment: I would also add that the next step would be to add a IoC container (In my own optinion).

Comment: @Ortund I would personally have it still take place in the controller, but you're free to do that wherever you wish. As Jamie also pointed out, IoC is a nice little pattern you can use if your repositories start getting complicated. You can see an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615139/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Dependency-Inver)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read this
http://chsakell.com/2015/02/15/asp-net-mvc-solution-architecture-best-practices/

Answer (score 0):

Larger proyets ?
Maybe https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

I use this in some big requests.